# Searching a portion of vector in c++

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stl, std

I have a vector which contains unsigned integers in sorted order. Now I want to apply binary search on the vector from a particular position of the vector to the end of it.

For example, my vector is:

```
vector<unsigned> vec;
vec.push_back(1); vector.push_back(2), vector.push_back(3); 

vector.push_back(4); 
vector.push_back(5); vector.push_back(6); vector.push_back(7); vector.push_back(8); 
vector.push_back(9); vector.push_back(10); vector.push_back(11); vector.push_back(12);
```

Now, I want to apply binary search on "vec" starting from the 6th position to the size of vector, i.e. I want to binary search on only the vector: starting from pos:6 to pos:11.

I know I can apply std:lower_bound(vec.begin(),vec.end(),9) on the entire vector, but I am not able to understand as to how can I apply it on a portion of the vector.  I want to find the position of "9" in the vector vec. I'll greatly appreciate any help on this

Comment: You can use `vec.begin() + n` to start at any `n`.

Comment: You're using C++11; why are you using so many `push_back` calls? Have you not heard of initializer lists?

Answer (score 6):

```
std:lower_bound(vec.begin() + 6,vec.end(), 9)
```

will search in the sub-vector from offset 6 to the end.